# SQLiteConnection Query<Int> returns 0 but Query<Foo> returns correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

First of all, I'm using Xamarin/C# with sqlite-net-pcl.

I create a table using SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable. T is one of my classes I can pass in, Here's an example:

```
    public class Foo : IDatabaseItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

}

After inserting a record, I want to return the last key inserted. SQLiteConnection.Insert unfortunately returns the amount of rows inserted instead of the row inserted.

```
        public int GetLastInsertedId()
    {
        return conn.Query<int>($"SELECT Max(Id) FROM {typeof(T).Name}").First();
    }
```

The problem is the function above, it always returns 0. I've tried removing the .First to analyse the entire object it returns and it'll return an IEnumerable which correctly has the amount of rows in the DB within, but all of the results are 0.

Interestingly if I modify my function to return the original class it was created from and remove the "Max(Id", it works.

```
    public Foo GetLastInsertedId()
    {
        return conn.Query<Foo>($"SELECT * FROM {typeof(T).Name}").First();
    }
```

I believe I'm not referencing the column name correctly, I'd love to view the table to see what I'm working with but unfortunately the version of android I'm using doesn't appear to let you view an SQLite database (from Visual Studio).

I get that I can use Linq queries to quickly get at the data I want, but it feels like returning an entire object from the database is a bit bulky when all I want is the Id, especially as the database grows.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I'm doing something daft...just can't suss out what.

Comment: use adb to copy the db file from the device/emulator to your desktop, then there are many tools you can use to examine the db file schema

Comment: and, according to the docs in you `Insert<MyClass>(myObject)`, `myObject.Id` should be populated with the PK after the `Insert`

Comment: Thanks, you're correct the original object has been modified with the new Id. I can work with this.